# need help fetching the id from mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have several forms, with different fields and purposes.

So i tought "hey, i'll build a generic **insert.php** page to input data to my database".
Ok, so far so good.

But now i need to link files to each record, so my form has a `<input type="file">` field.
What i really want to do is to allow the user to select several files (pictures, videos), create a directory named like the table plus the id of the record that is being inserted (`upload/$tablename/$id/`), store the files and add the path to the database.

Something like:

```
ID | NAME | WEBPAGE  | FILES  
01 | john | john.com | /upload/tblWebpages/01/  
02 | mike | mike.net | /upload/tblWebpages/02/  
19 | jimy | jimy.org | /upload/tblWebpages/19/
```

Because i don't know how many files will be inserted or their names, and later i intend to fetch all images in that directory and display it.

Is it possible to know the record ID from the table at the time the upload is being processed?
Because, as explained above, i'd like to store the files under a directory called **$ID**.
How should i add it to my query?

Alright, to the code:

**insert.php**

```
include('classes/class.upload.php');

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "xxxxx";
$database = "myDB";
$tabela = $_POST['tabela'];
$diretorio = "upload/".$tabela."/";

mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database" . mysql_error());

// create an array to hold your filnames
$images = array();
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['imagem'] as $k => $l) {
    foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
        $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
}      
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $handle = new Upload($file);
    if ($handle->uploaded) {
        $handle->Process($diretorio);
        if ($handle->processed) {
            echo 'OK ';
            // add the filename to the array
            $images[] = $handle->file_dst_pathname;
        } 
        else { echo 'Upload error: ' . $handle->error; }
    } 
    else { echo 'Upload error: ' . $handle->error; }
unset($handle);

}

foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
    if (!preg_match("/$value/i", $tabela)) {
        if (preg_match("/$field/i", 'data')) {$value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));}
        else {$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);}
        $campo .= $field . ',';
        $valor .= '\'' . $value . '\'' . ',';
        $query = "INSERT INTO $tabela ($campo) VALUES ($valor)";
        $query = str_replace(",)",")",$query);
        //echo " inside foreach  RESULT = $result  and  QUERY = $query  <br>";
    }
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
echo " outside foreach  RESULT = $result  and  QUERY = $query  <br>";

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

mysql_close();
```

**form.php** (simplified)

```
<form method="POST" action="insert.php" class="classeform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="namee" class="lbl-d-input">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="namee" id="namee" class="field">

  <label for="webpage" class="lbl-d-input">Webpage: </label>
  <input type="text" name="webpage" id="webpage" class="field">

  <label for="files" class="lbl-d-input">Files: </label>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" class="field-img">

  <input type="hidden" name="tabela" value="mytbl">

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Got it. Will post the answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with `mysql_insert_id()`

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your echo'd values?

I would start by writing out some debug code

For example:
After this line of code

```
if (!preg_match("/$value/i", $tabela)) {
```

I would put

```
print("Value Matched");
```

That way you know your getting into your for loop.  Also I noticed your not appending to your $query variable inside the loop so the db entry is never being added?

Comment: Hi Robert. Slightly changed my question. Would you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @RASG are you getting any different results as in seeing OK being printed?